# Azure Bastion SSH to Ubuntu VM fails after installing Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine, azure-bastion

I was using Azure Bastion to successfully SSH to my Ubuntu 16.04 VM - yesterday I installed Gnome.  After restarting the VM, I now get the following error when trying to connect to the VM via Bastion:

> "The target machine is either currently unreachable or
> username/password is not correct. Please re-verify your credentials.
> If the problem persists, please contact support."

My credentials are good.  Based on when this started, this has something to do with Gnome, it appears.

I did reach out to Azure support - thus far they haven't been able to help me resolve the issue.  They did provide this information as the *cause*:

> There are two perspectives to the connection process:
>
> The frontend part, which entails the connectivity from your physical
> machine to the Public IP address of the Bastion host via the Azure
> portal. This part functioned as expected.

> The backend part, which
> entails the connectivity from the Bastion host to the targeted VM. Our
> connection is showing that the VM linux-vm-0 (10.x.x.x) is refusing
> the connection.

Finally, when I check the Boot Diagnostics screen in the Azure Portal, the Gnome login screen is shown, so it seems the VM is up and running ok.

So I'm posting this issue here in case someone has any insight or has seen this before.

Comment: RDP wouldn't be my first choice to connect to a Linux system.  What service on the Ubuntu would provide RDP?

Comment: Sorry, I said RDP but I meant SSH.  I have updated the title and body of my post.

Comment: A subtle difference.  So, is the sshd running?

Comment: I"m not sure how I could determine that since I can't connect to the VM.

Comment: The Gnome login screen you mentioned?

Comment: The Gnome login screen is not something I can actually access.  In Azure, Boot Diagnostics simply shows you a screenshot of what the VM's screen looks like in its current state.  This helps you identify whether a connection issue is related to the VM being down or not.

Comment: That's all there is?  A real joy all that cloud stuff, isn't it?   No possibility to access the system logs?

Comment: Can you verify the "inbound port rules"?  Also, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-monitor for "Enable boot diagnostics".